# Issues while converting report from Deski to Webi

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am new to BO and facing following issues while converting reports from deski to webi:

1. Objects cannot be hidden in Web Intelligence documents
2. Page setup options are not implemented in Web Intelligence (First page number, page order, scale, Fit to N pages)
3. cross options for crosstabs are not available in Web Intelligence
4. Block filters on measures do not have the same behavior in Web Intelligence
5. The formula of a global filter in Desktop Intelligence cannot be migrated into a Web Intelligence report filter

I don't know how to deal with such errors. I am using BOXI 3.1 with SP2.

Answer (score -1):

Its been a while since I helped upgrade from 6.1 to XIR2, so this information may not be 100% correct.

All of the errors you show are report conversion errors that are not directly supported in WebI.  I'm pretty sure that the reports that have these errors should have moved to XIR3 but they do not look/act the same because of the errors listed above.

You have 3 options to resolve this:

1. Remove the features that the converter is notifying you of back in the source and try the conversion again.
2. Modify the converted report in XI R3 WebI to look and behave correctly.
3. Rewrite the report in XI R3 WebI from scratch.

All options require manual intervention unfortunately for each report that has errors.